# Suggestions for reliable cheap VPS ($10)?

Tags: hosting, vps

Does anyone have suggestions on reliable and cheap VPSes (up to around $10 each)? I found this link on a related question and was wondering if anyone had reviews for these services or others:

http://geekness.eu/vps-plans-under-10-dollars-a-month

To start, here are some services I've had personal experiences with:

1. **HostLatch ($6)** - My first ever VPS host. They don't answer all support tickets, but do answer if there's a big problem (server is down). Still, I've had many different VPSes with them and downtime happens, but usually gets resolved quickly. Great specs for the price.
2. **DMEHosting ($6)** - **TERRIBLE**. My servers were down about 5 separate times in the past few weeks, for well over a day's worth of time. On top of that, they had a server crash a few days ago so I lost all my data. From this alone, I had over 12 hours of downtime. I've lost much more money than I've saved with their cheap, but extremely unreliable hosting.
3. **HiVelocity ($8)** - The only OS they support is CentOS 4.5. I haven't had any downtime with them at all in the past month and a half. Support is fast, but isn't helpful, and web interface is terrible.

Comment: Product and service recommendations are off topic per the FAQ.

Answer (score 3):

Heh, I'm the author of that blog :) 
Anyway, I had a VPS with [HostGD](http://www.hostgd.com/) (as mentioned in the post) and they seemed quite good. Support was fast, I could change the OS of my VPS anytime, upgrade options etc. Cheap too, $4.95 IIRC.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a firm believer in "you get what you pay for". I know it's not what you asked, but if you stretch your budget just a little, you can get a $20 plan at rimuhosting.com.

Answer (score 0):

[VPSLink](http://vpslink.com/vps-hosting/)? I use them and they seem alright. Answers tickets quite quickly although the answer may not be what I was looking for. They have both OpenVZ and Xen based ones. I have also heard of [VPSVillage](http://www.vpsvillage.com/) but they did not reply the very first query email that I sent to them.

Answer (score 0):

Follow current promos and some reviews/comments for VPSes around $5/month at [Lowendbox](http://www.lowendbox.com/)